# Harmonic functions in the half-plane

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Denote by $\mathbb{H}$ the upper half-plane 
$$
\mathbb{H} := \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n > 0\right\}. 
$$
Suppose that $u \in C^2(\mathbb{H}) \cap C(\bar{\mathbb{H}})$ is a bounded harmonic function such that $u \leq 0$ on $\partial\mathbb{H} = \{ x_n = 0\}$. Is it possible to conclude that $u \leq 0$ in all of $\mathbb{H}$? I know this is the case for $n = 2$ but am unable to establish the general case $n \geq 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true in $n=2$. For example, $u(x,y)=y$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and positive for $y > 0$, even though $u(x,0) \le 0$. And it's not true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the same reason.

By assuming that $u$ is bounded, then you get the Poisson integral representation of $u$ from its boundary function, and that will give you what you want.

Comment: Yes but $u(x,y) = y$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{H}$. I think the boundedness assumption will be necessary somewhere.

Comment: @ImNotThereRightNow : Yes, you'll need further assumptions if you want the conclusion that you hoped for. I believe my answer is correct for the question that you asked.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a little confused now. How does this work with regards to my question? I'm assuming that $u$ is bounded.

Comment: @ImNotThereRightNow_ : Ah, I missed your assumption of boundedness in the question. Boundedness will give a Poisson integral representation, which will give you what you want.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Is there an approach that would also work for more general domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime : The approach I gave you works in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Well in all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can just apply Liouville's theorem to see that the function is actually constant. I was wondering about domains $U\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime : You just need the assumption of boundedness in the half-space.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks. I posted my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3026701/a-maximum-principle-for-bounded-functions-in-unbounded-domain) if you want to take a look!